# Box gets truncated using zoomed_inset_axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use `zoomed_inset_axes` but the box gets truncated as soon as it passes the frame of the main figure. I could not get any better with

- `f.tight_layout()`
- `f.subplots_adjust(bottom=...)`
- `'figure.autolayout': True`
- not even with hidden (white) text using `f.text` somewhere outside.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes, mark_inset

X = np.random.normal(.5,10,1000)
Y = np.random.normal(.5,10,1000)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,6))

ax.scatter(X,Y)

# # Setup zoom window
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc="center", bbox_to_anchor=(0,0))
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
axins.set_xlim([-15,0])
axins.set_ylim([-12,-3])

# # Plot zoom window
axins.scatter(X,Y)

f.tight_layout()
f.savefig('test.png', dpi=70)
```

[image: inset truncated]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `subplots_adjust` goes in the right direction. Don't use `tight_layout` afterwards as this would overwrite any settings done via `subplots_adjust`.

You may decide to opt for something like

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
```

to make some space for the inset in the lower left corner of the figure.

Then you need to position the inset. Since here you're working in the lower left corner, this is relatively easy. The `loc` parameter needs to be set to the lower left corner and you may stick to the `bbox_to_anchor=(0,0)` position. Then just add some padding via `borderpad=3` (in units of font size), such that the inset axes' labels are still visible,

```
zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0,0), borderpad=3)
```

Complete code:

```css
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import zoomed_inset_axes, mark_inset

X = np.random.normal(.5,10,1000)
Y = np.random.normal(.5,10,1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
ax.scatter(X,Y)

# # Setup zoom window
axins = zoomed_inset_axes(ax, 2, loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0,0), borderpad=3)
mark_inset(ax, axins, loc1=2, loc2=4, fc="none", ec="0.5")
axins.set_xlim([-15,0])
axins.set_ylim([-12,-3])

# # Plot zoom window
axins.scatter(X,Y)


#fig.savefig('test.png', dpi=70)

plt.show()
```

[image]

In general, you have a lot of options to position and size the inset. I recently created a new example on the matplotlib page: [Inset Locator Demo](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html), which is currently only available in the devdocs, to show the interplay between the different parameters (in that case for `inset_axes` - but it totally applies to `zoomed_inset_axes` as well).

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I could not get it to work properly on my problem as every parameter seems to be relative to the others but I managed to enlarge the area enough to crop it with `briss` afterwards. Thats not really productive in general but just in time for the talk and way better than the crappy image I grabbed from `plt.show()` previously  ... :-) When I find the time, I can try to analyze where this MWE diverges from my problem and possibly update the question.